# Send parallel requests to Mongo and continue when all requests are finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I have the issue with MongoDb JavaScript requests where I first retrieve array of posts (1) then I need to make 10 requests (2) for extra data for each post then I finish it with other work (3).

The issue is that I have found only solution that runs in order 1>3>2 or in order 1>2>2>..2>2>3 where it is waiting at 2 for previous requests to be finished before going with new one.

The best solution for me will be fire all (2) requests at once and when they are all finished continue with rest of the work (3) like this: 1>22...22>3.

```
async loadPosts() {
 const posts = await this._dbPosts.find({}, {limit: 10}).toArray()
 console.log(1)
 await posts.forEach(async post => {
  post.liked = await this._checkLikeOf(post)
 })
 console.log(3)
}

async _checkLikeOf(post) {
 const result = await this._dbLikes.findOne({id: this._auth.user.id, [`likes.${post._id}`]: true})
 console.log(2)
 return !!result
}
```

In this case all requests from _checkLikeOf() are sent without waiting for previous request to finish and my console logs is 1>3>2.

```
async loadPosts() {
 const posts = await this._dbPosts.find({}, {limit: 10}).toArray()
 console.log(1)
 for (let workout of workouts) {
  workout.hearted = await this._checkHeartOf(workout)
 }
 console.log(3)
}

async _checkLikeOf(post) {
 const result = await this._dbLikes.findOne({id: this._auth.user.id, [`likes.${post._id}`]: true})
 console.log(2)
 return !!result
}
```

With this solution, I get the correct order but every check of like waits for the previous one to finish. So I get 1>2>2>...>2>2>3 which is very slow.

I am looking for solution that is something in between, that would get all posts, then send all 10 requests to check like and after all 10 are finished I would like to continue with (3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can await an array of promises with Promise.all

```
async loadPosts() {
 const posts = await this._dbPosts.find({}, {limit: 10}).toArray()
 console.log(1)
 await Promise.all(posts.map(post => this._checkLikeOf(post)))
 console.log(3)
}

async _checkLikeOf(post) {
 const result = await this._dbLikes.findOne({id: this._auth.user.id, [`likes.${post._id}`]: true})
 console.log(2)
 return !!result
}
```